# How does one save a canvas as a jpeg then save that jpeg to system?

Tags: android, canvas, jpeg

I've been looking to do this so I can save images in my drawing program. I've looked online and on SO and the ones I've found either don't work or have custom classes and methods that are not shown. I really can't figure this out. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673582/android-save-canvas-screen-as-bitmap) and [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/649154/android-bitmap-save-to-location)

This should be enough to save a canvas to your sdcard :)
Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much I had not seen that 2nd one.